# SSO of a force.com site with another force.com site in same org

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com, force.com-sites, single-sign-on

Org has 2 customer portals/sites e.g.

```
abcd.secure.force.com/xxxx
abcd.secure.force.com/yyyy
```

Most users have access to both portals, users have same set of credentials for both of the portals.

If user logins into one portal(say xxxx) & clicks on URL of another portals(url of yyyy), he is directed to login page of the 2nd portal(login page of yyyy).

I believe, as both sites are on same domain, have same set of credentials; need of having to enter same credentials once again can be avoided.

How can we ensure that - Login into one force.com site, logins user in 2nd site as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've created my own login objects, classes, and pages where I keep track of users, and when they log on, I create my own `SessionId` and store the info in an `object` + a client side `Cookie`.  Then, I have a method (used in the `Action` parameter of `apex:page`) that validates my session for every `Portal Site page` visited.

I too have multiple sites for a single org with users existing among all of my `portals`.  I differentiate `Portal sessions` by the unique `cookie name` for that particular Portal (+ the `record` where the Session info is stored).

If you'd like to know more about my setup (including some `code`), let me know, and I can post some details.

---

**Some Details:**

We manage multiple orgs, and each org may contain a number of Sites.  Additionally, each site generally uses different `sObjects` as "User records" (e.g. the associated user record is an `Account` record or `Employee__c` record).  So, after creating a handful of Sites (custom *portals* for different client needs), each with their own login page & home page & ..., I began to see how to generealize this process.

It's split into a few steps:

**Step 0:**
For security, when a user logs in, a `SessionID` is created (a long randomly generated string) and is stored in a Cookie (along with the User's username).  Then, whenever the user navigates to any of the other site pages, I first call a method in the `action` attribute of `apex:page` that verifies the `SessionID` (along with checking the `SessionID` isn't "too old").

I had to create code to do this function (obviously), and I realized this process could be generalized.  (*more to come about this below*)

**Step 1:**
Since each "User record" may belong to a different sObject, and I want to use this code across many orgs (not necessarily sharing the same custom sObjects), I needed to dissociate the "User records" from the `Username__c`, `Password__c`, Security-Questions, `SessionID` data.  So, I created a custom object called `Portal__c` to house User-information and Session-data as well as Site-specific data accomplished by creating a number of `RecordType`s for `Portal__c`.

**`RecordType = Portal`:**  Houses Site parameters.  e.g.

- Session `Cookie` Name
- Which Site the record belongs to
- How long the allowable Session Length should be (before requiring the user to re-login.)
- Which sObject designates the "User Record" (along with noting what the User-`RecordType` is.)
- The name of the `lookup-field` in the `Portal__c:User` (i.e. the `Portal__c` record with the "`User`" `RecordType`) [*more about the `User RecordType` in a sec*]
- I have a set of string fields called `Login_Page__c`, `Home_Page__c`, `Register_Page__c`, `Error_Page__c`, `Expiration_Page__c`, `Forgot_Page__c` where I can set the name of the corresponding VF Page.  (This allows for easy navigation.)

**`RecordType = User`:**

Since each User record could be attached to **different sObjects** (like `Account` or `Employee__c`), we will need a lookup to each of these different sObjects.  To make administration easier, I create a different "User"-`RecordType` for each Site.  (Tt is sufficient to have a different `RecordType` per distinct User-record-sObject.)  This is why I allow the `Portal__c:User` records to have different `RecordTypes`.

The `Portal__c:User` records have:

- Username
- Password (encrypted)
- lookup to the associated "User Record"
- picklist of Security Questions
- Security Answer (encrypted)

**`RecordType = Session`:**

Houses Session Data and has a lookup to the associated Portal__c:User record.  Every time a user logs in, a new `Portal__c:Session` record is created.

There's not much here:

- SessionID (encrypted)
- lookup to Portal__c:User record
- Long Text Area field to house the Session History (an attempt to reduce the # of records created since the cost of each record is independent to how much data is stored within it).  I have code that writes the Session History to this field whenever a User navigates through the Site.

**Step 2:**
I created an Apex class called `Portal` to manage all this Portal and User information in a really easy-to-use way.  In fact, it mimics some of the functionality of `ApexPages.StandardControllers`:

- I wrote a lot of back end code to manage creating and verifying the Portal Sessions.
- Whenever a user navigates to a Site page, a new `Portal` instance is created, and it collects all the relevant data.
- The instance gives you the associated `User-record` and `id` just like a `StandardController` would.
- It's very easy to verify the SessionID, and if it is invalid, it redirects to the LOGIN page automatically.
- There are tools to navigate to different pages.

E.g.:

```
Portal portal = new Portal('mySiteName');
pageReference goHome = portal.getPage(Portal.Page.HOME);
id myRecordId = portal.getUserId();
pageReference verifySessionResult = portal.getSessionCheck();
pageReference theLoginPage = portal.loginPage();  // an easy escape to the login page
```

---

That's essentially it.  It's really cool because it's a breeze to create new portal!  The only real-work is creating the VF pages.

I'm still tweaking everything, and there is definitely room for improvement.

Comment: We have achieved that by actually opening one portal in another in hidden iframe. This way we manage to receive cookies of both portals in browser.

Comment: I would like to know our way of doing this. Code may be unnecessary but you can explain this in bit more detail.

Comment: I added an update :)